# How to Add repeater field into profile form Ultimate member plugin

Tags: wordpress, membership, user-management, directory-listing, jquery.repeater

I want to create simple community directory for that I am using Ultimate Member plugin. I want admin to manage all the things from front end.

Every member will have his family members and for this I want a repeater field (with add/remove button) so admin can add details of user's family members details too.

How to add repeater field with other sub field at front end in Ultimate Member plugin and or any other option if available to fulfill these requirements.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried to accomplish this show your efforts what have you done till now..

Comment: I have not edit any code yet but I found this plugin extension https://suiteplugins.com/downloads/relationships-for-ultimate-member/ I dont know weather It will help or not.

Comment: this is the paid extension. we cant help you with that.. and this is the custom coding work so if you tried to solve it by yourself and stuck somewhere then somebody can help you.. no one will write the complete code..

Comment: I am not asking for complete code I just want someone to guide if anyone has done this kind of stuff and also used Profile grid plugin and also edited it to take over admin part to front end but in that plugin I am not able to edit others user profile as admin in front end and thanks for your consideration